# Support Basic Authentication + LDAP and Pre-Authenticated at the same time

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security

I have a security app context which works fine with Pre-authentication.

I would want to know if it is possible to have both Basic Authentication (With LDAP Bind as authentication manager) and Pre-authentication effective at the same time:

If container provides principal name, we will rely on it (and go to LDAP to get user details), and if pre-authentication of container does not happen (e.g. we have deployed in Jetty for testing without pre-authetication), we would want Basic Authentication to be used which in turns authenticated by LDAP Bind.

Is it something possible? How can I do it?

Here is my existing (simplified) app context:

```
<s:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled"
    proxy-target-class="true" />

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <s:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <s:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,preAuthenticatedFilter" />
    </s:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <property name='securityContextRepository'>
        <bean
            class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
            <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='true' />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="preAuthenticatedFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.j2ee.J2eePreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter">

    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <s:authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticatedAuthProvider"   />
</s:authentication-manager>

<bean id="preAuthenticatedAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" >
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper" >
            <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="contextSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <!-- some config skipped -->
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsService" >
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ldapUserSearch"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"/>
    <property name="userDetailsMapper"  ref="fooUserDetailsMapper" />
</bean>
<bean id="fooUserDetailsMapper" class="com.foo.FooUserDetailsMapper" />

<bean id="ldapUserSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <!-- some config skipped -->
</bean>

<bean id="ldapAuthoritiesPopulator"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
    <!-- some config skipped -->
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.simple.SimpleLdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
</bean>



<bean id="ldapAuthorities" class="com.fil.ims.LdapAuthoritiesServices" />
```

I have tried the followings but none of them works

1. add a new ldap authentication provider (`org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider`), and add one more `<s:authentication-provider>` entry under `<s:authentication-manager>`, or
2. add a separate `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter`, which points to a new `<s:authentication-provider>` which points to the new ldap authentication provider  (It is complaining for `"An AuthenticationEntryPoint is required"`.)

What should be the right way to do so?

From my bare understanding, seems 2 should be the right way, if someone can give me some direction, it will be good enough.

Thanks